# Fast math expression parsing in python

Tags: python, sympy

I need to store big amount of math formulas in json and then evaluate them in python with various arguments. And do it fast
Example of formula: `1015995338000000 - (1.180266595461174895340000000E+28 / (11616850504302 + input * 12.884))`

evaluation code:

```
input = Symbol("input")
parsed = parse_expr(formula, local_dict={"input": input})
results = []
for input_value in values:
  results.append(Decimal(str(parsed.subs(input, input_value))))
```

Now I use sympy's `parse_expr`, but it too slow and also have overhead with casting `Float` to `Decimal`.

I's there more optimal way to eval expressions with sympy? Or faster library in python?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722995/writing-a-fast-parser-in-python) mentions some libraries that may help you.

Comment: How powerful of a parser do you need?